# Find the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n}{\ln(n)}$ where $a_{n} = \int_{1}^{e} \ln^{n}(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, derivatives, contest-math

First I tried to solve this problem by noticing that:
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{k}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\int_{1}^{e}\ln^{k}(x)dx = \int_{1}^{e}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln^{k}(x)dx \\= \int_{1}^{e}\frac{\ln^{k+1}(x)-\ln(x)}{1-\ln(x)}dx,$$
but this didn't really help.

Then I arrived at the equivalent form $a_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}e^{x}dx$ which yields:
$$a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_n = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}-x}{1-x}e^xdx.$$

My last attempt was to introduce a new function $F(t) = \int_0^1x^ne^{tx}dx$.

$$F^{\prime}(t)= \frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1x^ne^{tx}dx =\int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial t}x^ne^{tx}dx=\int_0^1 x^n e^{tx} xdx = \int_0^1x^{n+1}e^{tx}dx.$$

By doing IBP and simplifying I got this differential equation:
$$ F^{\prime}(t)= \frac{e^t}{t}-\frac{n+1}{t}F(t)$$ which I don't know how to solve.

Comment: may help https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h468892p2624827

Comment: $$ F^{\prime}(t)= \frac{e^t}{t}-\frac{n+1}{t}F(t)$$

Rearrage:

$$ F'(t) + \frac{n+1}{t} F(t) = \frac{e^t}{t}$$

For the above DE , the integrating factor is given as:

$$ \mu' = \frac{n+1}{t} \mu$$

Once we solve,

$$ \mu =e^{n+1} t$$

We now have:

$$ F(t)  =  \frac{1}{e^{n+1} t }\left[e^{n+1} e^t +C\right]$$

Comment: In the title you have $a_{n} = \int_{1}^{e} \ln^{n}(x)dx$ and then at the beginning of the post you're using $a_{k} = \int_{0}^{1} \ln^{k}(x)dx$. Which one is the intended form?

Answer (score 7):

For every $n \geq 2$, one has
$$a_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}e^{x}dx = \left[x^ne^x \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1nx^{n-1}e^x dx = e-na_{n-1}$$

Adding $na_n$ to both sides, you get $(n+1)a_n = e-n(a_{n-1}-a_n)$, which rewrites as $$a_{n-1}-a_n = \dfrac{e}{n}-a_n-\dfrac{1}{n}a_n$$

Summing this for $n=2$ to $N$, you get that for every $N \geq 2$
$$a_2-a_N = e(H_N-1)-\sum_{n=2}^N a_n - \sum_{n=2}^N \dfrac{a_n}{n} \quad \quad (*)$$

where $H_N = \displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^N \dfrac{1}{n}}$is the partial sum of order $N$ of the harmonic series.

But one has directly $$0 \leq a_n = \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}e^{x}dx \leq e \int_0^1 x^n dx = \dfrac{e}{n+1},$$

so the LHS of $(*)$ is bounded, and the second series in the RHS of $(*)$ converges, so $(*)$ gives directly that
$$ \sum_{n=2}^N a_n \sim eH_N$$
and because $H_N \sim \ln(N)$, you get that
$$\boxed{\lim_{N \rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{1}{\ln(N)}\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^N a_n} =e}$$

Answer (score 5):

This certainly is not a super formal answer however I do believe this can be formalised. I started from [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)  and asked about following limit $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\int_{1}^e\ln^nx\ \mathrm{d}x}{\ln \big(\frac{n}{n-1}\big)}.$$  Since the integral can be evaluated as @
RamanujanXXV pointed out I looked at the asymptotic behavior of the integral  $$\displaystyle\int_{1}^e\ln^nx\ \mathrm{d}x\approx \frac{e}{n}.$$ However it is easy to see that $$\ln \Big(\frac{n}{n-1}\Big)\approx \frac{1}{n-1}.$$ So the limit is equal to $e$.

Comment: Seems ok to me, good job!

Comment: Well some people think differently I am guessing that symbol $\approx$ can be treated here as something very unformal. However it is not. When I use $a_n \approx b_n$ I mean $a_n/b_n\to 1$.

Comment: Actually, if you already know that $$a_n =\displaystyle\int_{1}^e\ln^nx\ \mathrm{d}x\sim \frac{e}{n}$$ then you don't need Stolz-Cesaro to conclude. Indeed you can sum the equivalents to get directly $$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k \sim e \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k} \sim e \ln(n)$$ which gives the desired conclusion.

Answer (score 3):

Let us notice that
$$a_n=\int_{0}^{1}x^n e^x\,dx = \frac{e}{n+1}-\int_{0}^{1}x^n (e-e^x)\,dx.=\frac{e}{n+1}-R_n.$$
If we prove that the remainder term $R_n$ is sufficiently small we are done. The function $f_n(x)=x^n(e-e^x)$ is non-negative over $(0,1)$ with a root with multiplicity $n$ at the origin and a simple root at $1$. By the convexity of the exponential function $\frac{e-e^x}{1-x}$ is bounded between $e-1$ and $e$ over $[0,1]$, so

$$ R_n \leq e \int_{0}^{1} x^n(1-x)\,dx = \frac{e}{(n+1)(n+2)}<\frac{e}{n^2}.$$
This immediately gives
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k = e(H_{n+1}-1)+O(1) = e\log n+O(1). $$

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your ingenious ideas. I came up with a fairly simple answer combining the concepts I saw presented here.

$$a_n = \int_1^{e} \ln^{n}(x)dx = \int_0^{1}x^{n}e^{x}dx$$
$$\int_0^1 x^n e^x dx \leq e \int_0^1 x^ndx = \frac{e}{n+1} \implies a_n \leq \frac{e}{n+1}$$.

$$\int_0^1x^{n}e^x dx > \int_0^1x^{n+1}e^x dx \text{ (because we are working in the interval } (0, 1))$$

$$\int_0^1x^ne^xdx > e - (n+1)\int_0^1 x^n e^x dx$$

$$(n+2)\int_0^1x^ne^xdx > e \implies a_n = \int_0^1x^n e^x > \frac{e}{n+2}$$

Finally we arrive at the double inequality:
$$\frac{e}{n+2} < a_n \leq \frac{e}{n+1}$$

Then as $n \to \infty \text{, we can use the Squeeze Theorem using the double inequality above.}$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_1 + a_2 + a_3 + ... + a_{n}}{\ln(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{e(H_{n} - 1)}{\ln(n)} = e \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{H_n - 1}{\ln(n)} = e \cdot 1 = \boxed{e}$$

Comment: Be careful, "$ a_n \to \frac{e}{n+1}$" does not mean anything. Instead, you should sum your inequalities and apply squeeze theorem.

Comment: this is what I was picturing in my mind, but since this is a context problem you can be looser.